# Why am I getting the error “Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address ....)” in this C code?

Tags: c, exc-bad-access

I have received this error I have no clue why. The code works with initializing and assigning other variables before the error but always throws this exception at the final line in this code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include "math.h"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...

    FILE *BetaDecay1;

    FILE *BetaDecay2;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    int nProtons = 83; // Bismuth-210
    int nNeutrons = 210 - nProtons;
    int AtomicWeight_Bi210 = 210;

    // BETA (—) DECAY

    int nProtons_after = nProtons + 1;
    int nNeutrons_after = nNeutrons - 1;

    double massElectron = 9.10938E-31; // kg, kilograms

    double r0 = 1.25E-15; // m, meters
    double radius_Bi210 = r0 * ( AtomicWeight_Bi210^(1/3) );

    double xPointOfBetaRelease = radius_Bi210;
    double yPointOfBetaRelease = 0;
    double zPointOfBetaRelease = 0;

    double xBetaPos = xPointOfBetaRelease;
    double yBetaPos = yPointOfBetaRelease;
    double zBetaPos = zPointOfBetaRelease;

    double Qvalue_MeV = 1.161292E6;
    double Qvalue_Joules = Qvalue_MeV * 1.60217657E-13;

    double magnitudeBetaVelocity;
    double arrayOfEnergies1[180000];
    double arrayOfEnergies2[324000000];

    int iteration1 = 0;
```

Comment: Show the end of your main function!

Comment: `arrayOfEnergies2` attempts to declare several Gb worth of array on the stack.  This will overflow your available stack.  You might be able to move this to the heap, using `malloc`, but you should consider whether you really need 300 million `double`s

Comment: `double radius_Bi210 = r0 * ( AtomicWeight_Bi210^(1/3) );` does not do what you think it does. `^` is bitwise exclusive or, `1/3` is 0.